# iOS Objective C Webservice call

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-services

Need help on consuming a basic web service and displaying its details in a list in iOS (Obj C), mostly displaying json data.
I am a beginner and have no clue where to start.
also if you guys can suggest any good tutorial sites for iOS (Obj C), it'll be super helpful.

Comment: http://www.appcoda.com/fetch-parse-json-ios-programming-tutorial/

Comment: Is My answer helpful for you?

Comment: Yes it was Saurabh. Thanks matey. And you too Dev.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the NSUrlSession class to call the Web service.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
    NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=apple&media=software"] completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
        NSLog(@"%@", json);
    }];

    [dataTask resume];
}
```

for more information visit the link:
https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/networking-with-nsurlsession-part-1--mobile-21394

Answer (score 0):

You can used same methods in swift 3. Please find code below

```
let session = URLSession.shared
        //
        let url = "https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=apple&media=software"
        let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: URL(string:url)!) { (data, response, error) in
            print("\(data)")
            do {
                let parsedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as! [String:Any]
                print(parsedData)

            } catch let error as NSError {
                print(error)
            }
            print("\(response)")
        }
        dataTask.resume()
```

Hope its helpful for you for swift coding, Happy coding :)